# Nginx processing URLs with hashTags "#" and giving 404 errors on error.log

Tags: jquery, nginx, history, hashtag

I use JQuery History plugin to load parts of the page using AJAX, but I found Nginx producing 404 errors on error log for pages to hashtags
ex

```
http://example.com/#/load=content&page=1
```

Answer (score 0):

That is strange... Hashtags should never be sent to the server, they should be client-side only thing. I've tried putting this in the URL manually (i.e. `http://localhost/show-server.php/#/load=content&page=1`) and used this script to test and I cannot make it go to the logs in any case. The script displays everything in `$_SERVER` and it's not there either, as expected. I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 / Firefox 10.0, if that changes anything.

If nothing else, you can use [rewrite](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) to remove this, e.g. something like this:

```
rewrite ^(.*)#.*$ $1;
```

Comment: I think maybe some bots rewrite the hashtags '#' into '%23' and send the request to server